# Cannot find installed bin file

Tags: installed-programs

Installed Linuxx64Cmaptools bin from [here](http://cmap.ihmc.us/). Everything went fine, (installation menu steps OK successful install)   installed in root as far as I can remember.

But I cannot find the program (also not by searching).

Comment: Did you look inside /opt directory?

Answer (score 3):

The executable is a shell script with the name `CmapTools`. Per default, the installation folder is `IHMC CmapTools`. If you have installed in `/root`, the path to the executable is

```
/root/IHMC\ CmapTools/CmapTools
```

If you haven't changed any path in the installation process, your path is

```
/home/theo/IHMC\ CmapTools/CmapTools
```

---

For a better desktop integration, create a [desktop file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

---

You *could* search the file in your system via

```
find / -type f -name 'CmapTools' 2>/dev/null
```

---

Another thing, maybe its interesting, is `Uninstall\ CmapTools` in the same path to remove the application.

Comment: ok thanks a lot !         /root/IHMC\ CmapTools/CmapTools
started the program !

Comment: As you're a reputation 11 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: @Theo Don't thank A.B.!  **;-)** If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!